# Optimize CSS for multiple landing pages

Tags: css

With CSS in additional CSS in WordPress, I'm trying to hide a form from three of the landing pages. Adding CSS as

```
body.page-id-4077 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base {
    display: none;
}
```

works while doing something like below doesn't.

```
body.page-id-4077 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base, body.page-id-4082 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base, body.page-id-4086 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base, {
    display: none;
}
```

Please advise me as to what the correct way is that I need to follow to include CSS for multiple pages as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last comma from your code:

```
body.page-id-4077 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base, 
body.page-id-4082 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base, 
body.page-id-4086 .bg-tan-darker.color-white-base {
    display: none;
}
```